# C++11 vector argument to thread appears uninitialized

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I am trying to create a proof of concept for inter-thread communication by meanings of shared state: the main thread creates worker threads giving each a separate vector by reference, lets each do its work and fill its vector with results, and finally collects the results.

However, weird things are happening for which I can't find an explanation other than some race between the initialization of the vectors and the launch of the worker threads. Here is the code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <thread>


class Case {
public:
    int val;
    Case(int i):val(i) {}
};

void
run_thread (std::vector<Case*> &case_list, int idx)
{
    std::cout << "size in thread " << idx <<": " << case_list.size() << '\n';
    for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
        case_list.push_back(new Case(i));
    }
}

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int nthrd = 3;
    std::vector<std::thread> threads;
    std::vector<std::vector<Case*>> case_lists;

    for (int i=0; i<nthrd; i++) {
        case_lists.push_back(std::vector<Case*>());
        std::cout << "size of " << i << " in main:" << case_lists[i].size() << '\n';
        threads.push_back( std::thread( run_thread, std::ref(case_lists[i]), i) );
    }

    std::cout << "All threads lauched.\n";

    for (int i=0; i<nthrd; i++) {
        threads[i].join();
        for (const auto cp:case_lists[i]) {
            std::cout << cp->val << '\n';
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Tested on [repl.it](https://repl.it) (gcc 4.6.3), the program gives the following result:

```
size of 0 in main:0
size of 1 in main:0
size of 2 in main:0
All threads lauched.
size in thread 0: 18446744073705569740
size in thread 2: 0
size in thread 1: 0
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
  what():  std::bad_alloc
exit status -1
```

On my computer, besides something like the above, I also get:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

**It appears thread 0 is getting a vector that hasn't been initialized, although the vector appears properly initialized in main.**

To isolate the problem, I have tried going single threaded by changing the line:

```
threads.push_back( std::thread( run_thread, std::ref(case_lists[i]), i) );
```

to

```
run_thread(case_lists[i], i);
```

and commenting out:

```
threads[i].join();
```

Now the program runs as expected, with the "threads" running one after another before the main collects the results.

**My question is: what is wrong with the multi-threaded version above?**

Comment: You're invoking undefined behavior. Your reference to a element in your vector is invalidated as soon as you `push_back` the next element.

Comment: You need to fully populate `case_lists` before you construct any threads. (Or at least call `reserve` first.)

Comment: Yeah, try reserve() or an array. Or use indexes into the vector.

Comment: You can mitigate the reference issue by `reserve()`'ing the `vector` before you populate it: `case_lists.reserve(nthrd);` But yeah, it makes more sense to populate the vector before you start creating threads for it.

Comment: @tkausl not necessarily on the *next* `push_back`, but yeah, any subsequent `push_back` has the *potential* to invalidate existing references, but only when the `vector`'s `size()` equals its `capacity()` when `push_back()` is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

References (and iterators) for a `vector` are invalidated any time the capacity of the `vector` changes. The exact rules for overallocation vary by implementation, but odds are, you've got at least one capacity change between the first `push_back` and the last, and all the references made before that final capacity increase are garbage the moment it occurs, invoking undefined behavior.

Either `reserve` your total `vector` size up front (so `push_back`s don't cause capacity increases), initialize the whole `vector` to the final size up front (so no resizes occur at all), or have one loop populate completely, *then* launch the threads (so all resizes occur before you extract any references). The simplest fix here would be to initialize it to the final size, changing:

```
std::vector<std::vector<Case*>> case_lists;

for (int i=0; i<nthrd; i++) {
    case_lists.push_back(std::vector<Case*>());
    std::cout << "size of " << i << " in main:" << case_lists[i].size() << '\n';
    threads.push_back( std::thread( run_thread, std::ref(case_lists[i]), i) );
}
```

to:

```
std::vector<std::vector<Case*>> case_lists(nthrd);  // Default initialize nthrd elements up front

for (int i=0; i<nthrd; i++) {
    // No push_back needed
    std::cout << "size of " << i << " in main:" << case_lists[i].size() << '\n';
    threads.push_back( std::thread( run_thread, std::ref(case_lists[i]), i) );
}
```

You might be thinking that `vector`s would overallocate fairly aggressively, but at least on many popular compilers, this is not the case; both [gcc](https://tio.run/##TU7RbsMgDHznK6z1JWnaanltaH6log5J0FJA4FTqpv56mQvTNj/48N35MHq/nxBT2hiLyzpokMZFClpde/HH3TSSC/@ZSIOxdJh7IRjhqoytXg8VJtwBzirAdsvDrRZfArh44XgsOZKNnsKZehid60TWRxcgJxg4wXvHIKFlbBpTQ4koNnfwa5zPF4Uflam7XyV/gG4lkDLbovnUVf2a3sCN3H54VF6hoXvR8pq2w1KSHrkHTWuwfIZ4pPTEcVFTTHu2nrBp2vYb) and [clang](https://tio.run/##TU7RbsMgDHznK6z1JWnaanltaH6log5JrKWAgFTqpv56mQvTNj/48N35MDq3x0WZKaUNGVzWQYMkG6LX6tqLP@6mMVr/nwlxIBMPcy8EI1wVmer1UH7CHeCsPGy3PNxq8SWAixeOx5Ij2eiiP8ceRms7kfXResgJBCd47xgktIxNQzWUiGKzB7eG@XxR@FFR3f0q@QO0awQpsy3Qp67q1/QGduT2w6NyCinei5bXtBmWkvTI3eu4esNniEdKTxwXNYW0Z@sJm6ZtvwE) follow a strict doubling pattern, so the first three insertions reallocate *every* time (capacity goes from 1, to 2, to 4); the reference to the first element is invalidated by the insertion of the second, and the reference to the second is invalidated by the insertion of the third.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer (and the suggested fix). I have always somehow subconsciously equated vectors with arrays. Won't any more.